# JavaScript Array like object .map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

Hello I want to switch the ranking and cereal of my array around using the .map, however I am getting an undefined to the console.log.  Based on the awesome feedback I was able to get everything working, however I am still a bit confused about something.  For I am not sure how to match the cereal up with the ranking in reverse order?  I am totally stumped.

```js
var breakFastFood =[
  {
     cereal: "Captain Crunch",
     scale: "Yuck!"

  },
  {
    cereal: "Grape Nuts",
    scale: "Yum!"

 },
 {
  cereal: "Fruity Pebbles",
  scale: "Yuck!"

},
{
  cereal: "Oatmeal",
  scale: "Yum!"

}
];
var cereals = breakFastFood.map(function(bFood){
 return breakFastFood.cereal
});

var rank = breakFastFood.map(function(standing){
 return breakFastFood.scale
});

rank.forEach(function(rating){console.log(rating)});
cereals.forEach(function(food){console.log(food)});
```

Comment: What do you mean by *how to match the cereal up with the ranking in reverse order?*

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the function *parameter* in the *return* statement:

```js
var breakFastFood =[
  {
     cereal: "Captain Crunch",
     scale: "Yuck!"

  },
  {
    cereal: "Grape Nuts",
    scale: "Yum!"

 },
 {
  cereal: "Fruity Pebbles",
  scale: "Yuck!"

},
{
  cereal: "Oatmeal",
  scale: "Yum!"

}
];
var cereals = breakFastFood.map(function(bFood){
 return bFood.cereal
});

var rank = breakFastFood.map(function(standing){
 return standing.scale
});

rank.forEach(function(rating){console.log(rating)});
cereals.forEach(function(food){console.log(food)});
```

You can also use short hand property:

```js
var breakFastFood =[
  {
     cereal: "Captain Crunch",
     scale: "Yuck!"

  },
  {
    cereal: "Grape Nuts",
    scale: "Yum!"

 },
 {
  cereal: "Fruity Pebbles",
  scale: "Yuck!"

},
{
  cereal: "Oatmeal",
  scale: "Yum!"

}
];
var cereals = breakFastFood.map(({cereal}) => cereal);

var rank = breakFastFood.map(({scale}) => scale);

rank.forEach(function(rating){console.log(rating)});
cereals.forEach(function(food){console.log(food)});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the arguments of the [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback functions:

```js
var breakFastFood =[
  {cereal: "Captain Crunch", scale: "Yuck!"},
  {cereal: "Grape Nuts", scale: "Yum!"},
  {cereal: "Fruity Pebbles", scale: "Yuck!"},
  {cereal: "Oatmeal", scale: "Yum!"}
];

var cereals = breakFastFood.map(function(bFood)
{
    return bFood.cereal;
});

var rank = breakFastFood.map(function(standing)
{
    return standing.scale;
});

rank.forEach(function(rating){console.log(rating)});
cereals.forEach(function(food){console.log(food)});
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Note, you can also get the same result, iterating only once on the array of objects:

```js
var breakFastFood = [
  {cereal: "Captain Crunch", scale: "Yuck!"},
  {cereal: "Grape Nuts", scale: "Yum!"},
  {cereal: "Fruity Pebbles", scale: "Yuck!"},
  {cereal: "Oatmeal", scale: "Yum!"}
];

var cereals = [], rank = [];

breakFastFood.forEach(
    ({cereal, scale}) => (cereals.push(cereal), rank.push(scale))
);

rank.forEach((rating) => console.log(rating));
cereals.forEach((food) => console.log(food));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing the arguments incorrectly

```js
var breakFastFood =[{cereal: "Captain Crunch",scale: "Yuck!"},{cereal: "Grape Nuts",scale: "Yum!"},{cereal: "Fruity Pebbles",scale: "Yuck!"},{cereal: "Oatmeal",scale: "Yum!"}];

var cereals = breakFastFood.map(function(bFood){
 return bFood.cereal
});

var rank = breakFastFood.map(function(standing){
 return standing.scale
});

rank.forEach(function(rating){console.log(rating)});
cereals.forEach(function(food){console.log(food)});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `cereal` and `scale` property on the `breakFastFood`  array instead of on the individual objects passed in the **[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** call back.

```js
var breakFastFood = [{"cereal":"Captain Crunch","scale":"Yuck!"},{"cereal":"Grape Nuts","scale":"Yum!"},{"cereal":"Fruity Pebbles","scale":"Yuck!"},{"cereal":"Oatmeal","scale":"Yum!"}];
var cereals = breakFastFood.map(function(bFood) { return bFood.cereal; });

var rank = breakFastFood.map(function(standing) { return standing.scale;});

rank.forEach(rating => console.log(rating));
cereals.forEach(food => console.log(food));
```

Your code can be further simplified to use arrow functions `=>` and **[destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)**:

```js
const breakFastFood = [{"cereal":"Captain Crunch","scale":"Yuck!"},{"cereal":"Grape Nuts","scale":"Yum!"},{"cereal":"Fruity Pebbles","scale":"Yuck!"},{"cereal":"Oatmeal","scale":"Yum!"}];
const cereals = breakFastFood.map(({cereal}) => cereal);

const rank = breakFastFood.map(({scale}) => scale);

rank.forEach(rating => console.log(rating));
cereals.forEach(food => console.log(food));
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks

Comment: @binarie glad I could help out!

Comment: Gang, I made a mistake. How do I match up the cereal with the ranking. For example instead of captain crunch, next line yuk. I would like it to say "Yuck (next line) Captain Crunch. I am sorry for my mistake.  I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You were accessing the arguments correctly. Also (an extension to all the other answers), you could farther simplify this code using shorthand notation.

`bFood => bFood.cereal` is the same thing as

```
function(bFood) {
  return bFood.cereal;
}
```

And `rating => console.log(rating)` is the same thing as

```
function(rating) {
  console.log(rating);
}
```

These are called Arrow Functions. You can find out more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```js
var breakFastFood = [{
    cereal: "Captain Crunch",
    scale: "Yuck!"

  },
  {
    cereal: "Grape Nuts",
    scale: "Yum!"

  },
  {
    cereal: "Fruity Pebbles",
    scale: "Yuck!"

  },
  {
    cereal: "Oatmeal",
    scale: "Yum!"

  }
];

var cereals = breakFastFood.map(bFood => bFood.cereal);

var rank = breakFastFood.map(standing => standing.scale);

for (let i = 0; i < cereals.length; i++) {
  console.log(rank[i]);
  console.log(cereals[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!  This has really made a huge difference.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Gang, I made a mistake.  How do I match up the cereal with the ranking.  For example instead of captain crunch, next line yuk.  I would like it to say "Yuck (next line) Captain Crunch.  I am sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistakes in your code. The map function accept current value as argument so you had to rewrite your code like this:

```
var cereals = breakFastFood.map(function(bFood){
 return bFood.cereal
});
var rank = breakFastFood.map(function(standing){
 return standing.scale
});
```

It is means that bFool is the current item in mapped array and you can get it properties in function body.
But I think that the best way is to using good argument name like this

```
var rank = breakFastFood.map(function(breakFastFoodItem){
 return breakFastFoodItem.scale
});
```

or this

```
var rank = breakFastFood.map(function(item){
 return item.scale
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use
`return bFood.cereal` instead of `return breakFastFood .cereal` and 
`return standing.scale` instead of `breakFastFood.scale`

```js
var breakFastFood =[
  {
     cereal: "Captain Crunch",
     scale: "Yuck!"

  },
  {
    cereal: "Grape Nuts",
    scale: "Yum!"

 },
 {
  cereal: "Fruity Pebbles",
  scale: "Yuck!"

},
{
  cereal: "Oatmeal",
  scale: "Yum!"

}
];
var cereals = breakFastFood.map(function(bFood){
 return bFood.cereal
   });


var rank = breakFastFood.map(function(standing){
 return standing.scale
});

rank.forEach(function(rating){console.log(rating)});
cereals.forEach(function(food){console.log(food)});
```